# UWP MediaElement Not Closing

Tags: user-interface, uwp, mediaelement

I've added a MediaElement in my xaml.  When clicked it shows the player screen with image and  plays.  I want it to close and be removed after playing.  I've tried Close() with no effect.

```
  private async void MovieItemAsync(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaMainPage.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Videos/EMRON_Overview1.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);
        mediaMainPage.Play();
        //mediaMainPage.Stop();
        //mediaMainPage.Source = null;
    }
```

Here is my xaml:

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4">
            <MediaElement  x:Name="mediaMainPage"   AutoPlay="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

And:

```
 <Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="HelpItemBtn" Label="Help" Icon="Help" Click="HelpItemAsync" />
        <AppBarButton x:Name="MovieItemBtn" Label="Tutorial" Icon="Camera" Click="MovieItemAsync" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to close and be removed after playing. I've tried Close() with no effect.

Setting the `Source` property to null did work. If you want to remove the image in the MediaElement when the video has played to the end, you could set the `Source` property to null in its MediaEnded event handler.

```
<MediaElement  x:Name="mediaMainPage"   MediaEnded="mediaMainPage_MediaEnded"  AutoPlay="True"/>
```

```cs
private void mediaMainPage_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaMainPage.Source = null;
}
```